# SciPy constraints do not work properly when I try to minimize the objective function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have the following simple python code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def cons_function(x):

    return x[0] - 1000

def objective(x):
    a = x[0]
    
    return a ** 5

x0 = [0]
cons_dict = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun': cons_function}]
res = minimize(objective, x0, constraints=cons_dict)

print('x: ', res.x)
print('fun: ',res.fun)
```

And the output is as follows:

```
x:  [-2.64828354e+12]
fun:  -1.3026339977067573e+62
```

But the value of `x` is supposed to be greater than `1000`. And the minimum value of the objective function would be `10e+15`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial guess x0 is **not feasible** and contradicts your constraint as you can see by checking the return optimization result `res`:

```py
     fun: -1.3026339977067573e+62
     jac: array([2.45939306e+50])
 message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'
    nfev: 50
     nit: 16
    njev: 15
  status: 4
 success: False
       x: array([-2.64828354e+12])
```

You always have to use a feasible initial guess that satisfies all your constraints. Note also that your constraint is a simple bound on the variable, so it's recommended to pass it as a bound instead of the more general constraints:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x):
    a = x[0]
    return a ** 5

# 1000 <= x[0] <= None is equivalent to 1000 <= x[0] <= Inf
bounds = [(1000, None)]
x0 = [1002]
res = minimize(objective, x0, bounds=bounds)

print('x: ', res.x)
print('fun: ',res.fun)
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the documentation for the methods that you are using. Depending on the methods of optimization, constraints are used or even ignored. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Note

> If not given, chosen to be one of BFGS, L-BFGS-B, SLSQP, depending on
> whether or not the problem has constraints or bounds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. According to the documentation the method "SLSQP" would be a good choice for this problem, but it keeps giving the same output even after I set the "method" attribute. I also tried the other methods, but couldn't get the desired output.